# Which matrices $A$ have $f_{1} \neq 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been stuck on this problem for a while. I found a way to do but it seems inappropriate. I'm very grateful if anyone can help me solve this:

> > Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with entries in the field $F$ and let $f_{1}, f_{2}, ..., f_{n}$ be the diagonal entries of the normal form of $xI - A$. For which matrices $A$ is $f_{1} \neq 1?$

The way I did it is: The normal form of $A$ has diagonal entries including $1,1,..., 1, p_{r}, p_{r-1}, ..., p_{1}$. Here $r$ is number of factors in cyclic decomposition of $A$. So $f_{1} \neq 1 $ where the number of factors in the cyclic decomposition of $A$ is $n$. In this case, $A$ has $n$ characteristic vectors.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Even though your way to do it might seem inappropriate, it is still appropriate to put your approach here, so that we understand what you have tried. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I've already added my solution to this problem. I think it's wrong but I can't find why? Can you post your solution, please

Comment: I take it we are thinking of the Smith normal form of $xI-A$, and the $f_i$ are elementary divisors (whose product will be the characteristic polynomial of $A$)?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's Smith normal form. Normal form here is the form mentioned in Kunze Hoffman book, and $f_{i}$ is diagonal entries in the normal form of $A$

Comment: Sorry, but how can a function of the form $x-a$ be equal to $1$ for all $x$?

Comment: What if $A$ is the zero matrix?  $A$ does not have distinct eigenvalues (or characteric values, as you put it).  But the diagonal entries of $xI-A$ are all $x \neq 1$, and I take it this would be the "normal form".

Comment: Ok. zero matrix is a solution for this problem, because in that case $f_{1} = x$. But in general, which $A$ has this property?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: Sorry but I don't get what you mean. As I mentioned, the normal form of $A$ has diagonal entries in order : $1, 1, ..., 1, p_{r}, p_{r-1}, ... , p_{1}$. So why can't $f_{1} = 1$

Comment: @leducquang This is all very confusing to me. Do you agree that $f_i$'s are all polynomials of degree 1?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn:  I think you are confusing the diagonal entries of $xI-A$ with the diagonal entries of its (Smith) normal form, aka the elementary divisors or invariant factors of $xI-A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link discussing [invariant factors](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Elementary_divisors) of a matrix, which here are (apparently) the $f_i$, polynomials whose product is the characteristic polynomial of $A$ (necessarily of degree $n$) and which sequentially divide one another:

$$ f_i | f_{i+1} $$

Now by a degree argument, the only way to avoid $f_1 = 1$ is for all the invariant factors to be equal.  That is, if $f_1 \neq 1$, then $\deg(f_1) > 0$ and by the divisibility conditions, all $deg(f_i) > 0$.  But $\sum_i \deg(f_i) = n$ because their product is the characteristic polynomial of $A$ (determinant of $xI-A$), and this means all $deg(f_i) = 1$.  But monic first-degree polynomials $f_i|f_{i+1}$ only if they are equal.  Hence all the invariant factors are equal.

Now the minimal polynomial of $A$ is the least common multiple of its invariant factors, which by the divisibilty condition means $f_n$.  Since $deg(f_n) = 1$, $A$ must have a single "characteristic value" $r$ whose geometric multiplicity is $n$.  Equivalently $A = rI$ for some scalar $r \in F$.

Comment: The $f_i$'s are called *invariant factors*.

Comment: @YACP: Yes, a synonym I noted in a comment on the Question.

Comment: Wrong: the elementary divisors are the irreducible factors of invariant factors!

Comment: @YACP: Okay, I'm convinced!  I changed that...

Comment: @hardmath: I don't think if $A$ has single "character value" means $A = rI$. It's not clearly convincible. Can you prove that??? Maybe $A$ just needs to be similar to $rI$

Comment: Note the additional qualification, "whose geometric multiplicity is $n$".  This was meant to distinguish having "algebraic multiplicity $n$", i.e. that the characteristic polynomial is $(x - r)^n$, from the narrower condition of a full basis of eigenvectors corresponding to $r$.

Comment: Ok, I got it. We can derive this from the fact that A must be diagonalizable, right?

Comment: Let me embellish my answer to spell out the "degree argument" and that should clear things up.